# how to return a reference to an item inside map inside RefCell

Tags: rust

Before closing as dup please note that I am implementing a trait that requires

```
   fn get_value(&self, key: &str) -> Option<&Value>
```

So I cannot change the return type, and I need a 'persistent' thing to return a reference too

My starting implementation looks like this

```
    fn get_value(&self, key: &str) -> Option<&Value>{        
          self.symbols.get(key)
    }
```

where symbols is a hashmap. This works fine as the values were known statically. But now I need dynamic elements. (That are the result of some other calculations / lookup)

If this function had a `&mut self` it would be easy. I would just insert the value into my hash map

```
  fn get_value(&self, key: &str) -> Option<&Value>{        
          if let Some(v) = self.symbols.get(key){
             return Some(v);
          }
          let v = do_some_calculations(key);
          self.symbols.insert(key, v)
           self.symbols.get(key)
    }
```

But I am in a read only context. So I naively tried wrapping the HashMap in a `RefCell`. But I can find no recipe that works. The insert works fine after a `borrow_mut` but I can find no way to obtain a 'persistent' reference to the value. I think I have to resort to unsafe code.

Comment: Sigh. I knew it would get closed as I typed it. No that dup doesn't help at all as it has a very different set of constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`elsa`](https://docs.rs/elsa), a crate that uses unsafe code (so you don't have to write it yourself) to encapsulate this observation: if we never remove from a collection, and the elements are behind some indirection, we can safely insert to it using shared reference.

It provides [`FrozenMap`](https://docs.rs/elsa/latest/elsa/map/struct.FrozenMap.html) as an alternative to `HashMap`.

Comment: this is basically what I coded myself. In fact I realized I didnt need to keep multiple values, just the latest one so I have RefCell<Value> and update that via unsafe code

Comment: @pm100 This is unsound: one can replace the item while holding a reference to it, causing UB.

Comment: Why? Becuase I might change the value ?. But then how does the case where I had a pure map work. (No refcell). I return a refence to an entry in a map, I could remove that element invalidating the reference. But the compiler doesnt complain. I assume its down to what the caller does with the reference. I happen to know in this case that the immediately deref and clone.

Comment: @pm100 Without `RefCell`, the compiler ensures that if you remove the element (you have a mutable reference) you don't hold a reference to the item. With your unsafe code, this is no longer guaranteed. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=00d7d7eb7731c7b7f79b73f53b7f4b35. Run the code under Miri to see the UB.

Comment: _Iff_ between consecutive writes you have a mutable reference to the data, you can use `OnceCell`. Of course, if you can, it is better to redesign the trait.

Comment: not my trait - evalexpr owns it